# App has slugging behaviour

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My app is behaving sluggishly. If i pop up a UIActionSheet, for example, instead of rolling in smoothly, it stutters in over about 5 frames. I know ideally you should have as little amount of views on screen as possible, but that's what I've got anyway.

Any suggestions for speeding it up?

EDIT:

On my view i have:

Custom navigation bar in place of the regular one. It's a UIImageView, using an image file. It has a quartzcore shadow. It contains 3 buttons. 2 of these buttons have 2 UIImages each, for normal and highlighted, generated from code when the view is shown. The other button uses an image file for normal and for highlighted.

An image file for a background lies under that. On top of the background is a UITableView. By default, it doesn't have any cells (the user adds them). We'll ignore the cell, since it's slugging regardless of their being there or not.

The header of the tableview contains some labels, and an editable uitextview. The size of the header changes as more lines are added to the textview. It also has a background image, which is transparent to allow you to see the view's background image behind it. It's loaded from a file, and a texture image on top of that is also loaded from a file.

The footer is simply a background image loaded from a file with the same texture on top.

Comment: are create UI Calls on the main thread or on a separated background thread?

Comment: You sure you don't have some background task in a hard loop?

Comment: UI stuff is on the main thread, but everything is already set up at the point of the action sheet being shown.

Comment: Could you give us an idea of what you have on your view? I remember my entire app was running sluggishly like yours. I had a bunch of pictures with shadows on the view, and since I wasn't drawing the shadows well, it was slowing everything down. Once I changed the drawing process, everything worked. Give us an idea of what you have on your view as this is probably what is causing the slowness (or any background processes).

Comment: I've edited it with a description of what the view contains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Andrew, I'm afraid you haven't been quite specific enough to isolate the exact problem. However there are a couple of things I have picked out. Firstly, check your table view is set to be opaque. Also try to design your app so your table cells can be opaque. I'm assuming your design will allow this. You need to really know how to optimise view rendering performance if you want your table and it's cells to appear translucent over other content and it may be you would need to develop your own custom specialised alternative to UITableView if that is something you really need to know (can be done but quite advanced stuff).

Also you mention using Quartz shadow. You should be able to use UIKit for drawing shadows around images, unless you have some specialist requirement. Are you sure you need to use Quartz for what you want to do? Apologies if you already know this, but if you are fairly new to iOS development and have been looking up how to do shadows, you may have found the Quartz API's for doing that and assumed that is the solution, when (depending on what you need) you will probably be better off staying with UIKit. As a general rule of thumb, only use Quartz if you are sure you can't do what you want to do with just the UIKit API's.

Another thing to check. If you are using Quartz, then you are probably getting getting the graphics context for the UIImage view and drawing on the views context in drawRect: depending on how your view hierarchy is configured, and if you have your navigation bar view set to be transparent over the top of the UITableView, then your custom drawRect implementation may be getting called unnecessarily with every animation frame and this would be a big drain on performance.

Given the level of information you have given I'm having to guess a bit and can't give a precise answer. However for a definitive understanding of how to optimise UIView performance I recommend checking out this video (though you will need an Apple Developer account to be able to access it):

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/

Session 121 – Understanding UIKit Rendering

Hope this helps. Paul.

Comment: That's great, thanks. I wasn't aware I could do shadows using UIKit, i thought the only other solution was coregraphics (which would involve making a new UIView bigger than my existing on, under it, which would contain the shadow). That seemed like quite a bit of work, and i hadn't heard anybody mention that so i assumed quartzcore was the way to go.